# Search based on Priority queue

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

i need some help here.. am trying to implement a search result

conditions

1# it should fetch records that equals what keyword user enter on textbox(@SEARCH)

2# Along with the first condition It also fetch the matched records  which is entered on textbox(@SEARCH)

3# What keyword searched that should show 1st and other matches will 
   show after that( what i means priority queue)

4# It should check @loc paramater and fetch to that keyword.

```
@SEARCH NVARCHAR(100) = NULL,
@loc NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
as
select *
from tblBusinessCategory as b
    inner join tblUser as u on b.BusinessID=u.BusinessCategoryId
    inner join tblAddress as a on u.AddressId=a.AddressID
where b.BusinessName = @SEARCH and
a.City = @loc 
       OR a.State = @loc 
       and  b.BusinessName LIKE '%' + @SEARCH + '%'
```

Comment: Can you show some data to explain the example?

Comment: u mean database records (tables) ?

Comment: it doesn't need to be the data or the tables you have, but an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If i give keywords in both the text boxes the result is fetching correctly. But if i gave the keyword in textbox(@search) alone the result is not fetching

Comment: is this possible to set Priority queue.. Example: i have arun, arunkumar,arunraj etc in my table. if i search arun i want to display arun 1st then arunraj, etc.. 


if i search arun it fetch arunraj 1st and then arunkumar then arun..

do u understand my problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to order them based on that condition (b.BusinessName = @SEARCH):

```
select *
from tblBusinessCategory as b
    inner join tblUser as u on b.BusinessID=u.BusinessCategoryId
    inner join tblAddress as a on u.AddressId=a.AddressID
where a.City = @loc OR a.State = @loc 
       OR b.BusinessName LIKE '%' + @SEARCH + '%'
Order By case when b.BusinessName = @SEARCH then 0 else 1 end
```

I am not sure whether you want OR or AND in your where clause. If you want to mix OR and AND you should use parenthesis: `where (X = 0 or Y = 5) And Z = 20`